# JAX-RS implementation of link/element expansion?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

While reading documentation of Google Data API and Atlassian REST API, I found interesting functionality - link (or title, element expansion) - http://bit.ly/i3rKMw. I would like to implement this functionality in my Java project of web service server for our IS, but I can't find any proper solution or advices for implementation. My project is quite big with many services so I need some *robust* and most *automated* solution. I was thinking about how to implement it like an extension for RESTEasy and JAXB, but it seems to be very complicated.

Do you know some opensource projects which implements this functionality or any advices which could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Resteasy already provides an annotation based solution for this:

http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/#LinkHeader

This was added to version 2.0

Comment: Some other ways for hyperlinking resources using resteasy:http://soa.dzone.com/news/declarative-hyperlinking

Comment: Also, a tutorial for using RESTeasy hyperlinking:
http://www.lunatech-research.com/archives/2010/04/19/automatic-resource-link-discovery-resteasy-and-atom-links

Comment: This isn't what I'm asking for. I know Atom links, HeaderLinks and their RESTEasy support. I want to nest the associated element, see example from http://bit.ly/i3rKMw please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that any JAX-RS framework can provide such logic.
It actually a business logic: when you receive *expand* query parameter, expand the relevant element/section.

You'll need to implement it yourself.